# OutputPath error with nuget pack in nuget 2.2.3

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I am creating a NuGet package on the command line as follows:

```
nuget pack MyProject.csproj -Properties "Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCPU;OutputPath=." -Build
```

This works successfully with NuGet.exe 2.1.3, but when I updated to NuGet.exe 2.2.3 with NuGet.exe update -self, running this command now breaks with the following error:

```
The output path property is not set for project 'MyProject.csproj'. Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project. Configuration='Debug' Platform='AnyCPU'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project.
Done building project "MyProject.csproj"
Failed to build 'MyProject.csproj'
```

MyProject does live within a larger solution, but it has no dependencies on any other projects in that solution.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that got fixed with http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2920 and should be updated soon.